# Change pagination dynamically in ActiveAdmin or solutions for printing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm new to Activeadmin and rails and I need some help.

I have a model that is paginated and I want to allow the user to change the pagination value or disable it completely, so it can print (to a printer) all the records (or filtered ones) for instance.

I know I can set the pagination using @per_page in :before_filter, but I can't figure out how I can change this value during execution.

To solve the problem of needing to show all the unpaginated records I defined a custom page, but in this page the filter or scope don't work so it's kind of useless.

How can I create a Print button in Active Admin?

Answer (score 5):

This is a workaround to do it, I know it is not the best solution but it works ! :)
This is the app/admin/mymodel.rb file

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  before_filter :paginate
  #other code

  controller do
    def paginate
      @per_page = params[:pagination] unless params[:pagination].blank?
    end
  end

  index do
    panel "Pagination" do
      render partial: "paginate", locals: {resource: "mymodels"}
    end
    #other code
  end

  #other code
end
```

And for the app/views/admin/articles/paginate.html.haml

```
#pagination_form
  = form_tag do 
    = label_tag :pagination, "Number of " + resource + " per page : "
    = text_field_tag :pagination
    = submit_tag "Filter"

:javascript
  $("#pagination_form form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = "/admin/#{resource}?pagination=" + $("#pagination").val();
  })
```

Hoping that my answer can people with the same problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution and I'm answering my own question for someone who has the same problem.
It may not be the best solution but it works, if someone has a better way please share:

```
ActiveAdmin.register mymodel do
    before_filter :apply_pagination
    # other code

    index :download_links => false, :as => :table, :default => true do 
      if params[:pag].blank?
        div link_to(I18n.t("text_for_the_link"), 'mymodel?pag=1', :class => "class_for_link")
       else
        div link_to(I18n.t("print.print"), 'mymodel', :class => "class_for_link")                     
      end
      # other code
    end

    controller do
      def apply_pagination
         if params[:pag].blank?
           @per_page = 50
          else
           @per_page = 99999999                    
       end
       # other code
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out you can define this by registering the following line on the resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  config.per_page = [20, 50, 100, 200]
end
```

It automatically adds a select box in the index pagination with the preset values given in the array.